# How to identify field in a group type drupal

Tags: drupal, boolean, field, group

I have a checkbox and I want to display or not something based on the checkbox but I can't determine what should I write in Twig to identify the checkbox.

I tried the following example but it didn't work. My field is one of the field of a group type.

content.myfields.value

node.myfields.value

group_data.myfields.value

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

So I solved my problem.

The answer was really specific to my drupal website. We use group module as a sub websites generator. Since the group module doesn't provide variables for drupal field the former developers created an element in php in which we can add variables.

Example:
I added a boolean field named "X"
I don't have variable for X
So I add my field X to the custom element in my custom theme
Then I can call it using my_custom_element.X

Not sure it can be useful to other people.